# Escaping out of a jquery animate()

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I've got a little function here and I want to replace some of paramaters of the animate with the passed variables .

```
function anibut(side,dir) {
    button = $(this);
    button.animate({
        marginLeft: '-=3px'
    }, 200)
}
```

I'd like the Left in marginLeft replaced with side and the - in -=3px replaced with dir .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function anibut(side,dir) {
    var hash = {};
    hash['margin'+side] = dir + '=3px';
    button = $(this);
    button.animate(hash, 200)
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
anibut("Right", "+");
```

Comment: Which part do you not understand here?

Comment: Ah, hash is just a simple object, `{}`. I should've called it something else to make it clear. Basically, instead of passing in { marginLeft: ... }, we're creating an object with those properties, and then passing it. This allows us to use a dynamic key ("margin" Left or Right).